# Possible problem between heroku and parse server

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, parse-server

I'm working on a application which uses parse server as api, i deployed both on heroku.
When i try to save a user on my database i get this error: 
ParseError { code: 107, message: 'Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /classes/_User\n' }

Comment: Still didn't figure out what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just forgot to set the SERVER_URL in heroku settings.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it solves your problem.